# Service Provider ForceAuthn does not work in Chrome (but in InternetExplorer and Edge)

Tags: google-chrome, saml, saml-2.0

When using ForceAuthn=true in AuthnRequest then the prompt for Re-Authentication (in my case client certificate via Smartcard) works as expected in Internet Explorer 11 and Edge but not in Chrome. Chrome just logs me in without any prompt.

I checked all possible settings in Chrome, I tried all that I found in the AuthnRequest (setting explicit AuthnContextClassRef and/or AuthnContextDeclRef) but I cannot get it working.

Has anyone any idea for me what to check/search for?

I even deleted the cookies in chrome after the first login, but still chrome logged me in just that at the second login

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for replying so late. 
One possible explanation would be if the IdP doesn't support the Authentication Context given in the AuthnContextClassRef, and the Service Provider is flawed and doesn't check the SAML Response StatusCode.

For example, if the IdP is not accepting password, and you send:

```
<samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact"> 
    <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
        urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
    </saml:AuthnContextClassRef> 
</samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
```

the IdP will respond:

```
<samlp:Status> 
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder"> 
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:NoAuthnContext" /> 
    </samlp:StatusCode> 
</samlp:Status>
```

and the SP must then reject.

Have you traced the SAML Request and Response with a SAML tracing plugin in Chrome? And checked that the Request is actually valid XML?